# Get Advance Details provided while creating AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was creating new AWS EC2 instance, in step 1 I selected AMI Linux Image, In Step 2 after some basic details, I provided following advance details

```
#!/bin/bash
yum install httpd -y
yum update -y
service httpd start
chkconfig httpd on
echo "<html><h1>Hello Test Page!</h1></html>" > /var/www/html/index.html
```

Somehow this script did not execute after EC2 instance was ready. I have following questions,

1. Can we get log of what exactly happen in executing this script?
2. Also from console is it possible to get what values were specified in Advance details while setup an EC2 instance.

Comment: What tutorial are you following? What are Step1 and Step2?

Answer (score 0):

Login into your EC2 instance and check **/var/log/cloud-init-output.log** for any errors.

To check the user-data specified, I don't think you can see it on the console. But you can verify it using **http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/** after logging into EC2